# jQuery color animation plugin not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-animate

I have looked around on here but can not find out why this is not working properly. I want to make a simple fading in color background on hover. It is only working in Chrome but not Firefox or IE. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="sidemenu">
        <a href="#">Spiritual Ceremonies</a>
            <a href="#">Flower Ceremony</a>
            <a href="#">Ceremony Four Elements</a>
            <a href="#">Butterfly Ceremony</a>
            <a href="#">Non Denomination Ceremony</a>
            <a href="#">Mayan Wedding Ceremony</a>
            <a href="#" id="no">Civil Mexican Ceremony</a>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>
<script>
$("#sidemenu>a").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#943939",color: "#fff"}, 150 )}
        ,function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#dcacbb",color: "#8e5769"}, 150 );
        });             
</script>
```

Comment: By default, jQuery cannot animate colors.  If you're using a plugin, please edit your original post to include that missing information and add a link to the plugin's  website.

Comment: Sparky is correct.  I believe that jquery UI 1.8 solves the issue of animating color.  Just include jquery ui and it should work.

Comment: It may be a stupid answer, but did you try that with `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: @JamesL., Although jQueryUI also allows the animation of colors... the OP does not need jQueryUI if he's already using a color animation plugin, `jquery.animate-colors.js`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530866/jquery-color-animation-throws-invalid-property-value-intermittently , it might help

Comment: yeah it seems to be that he seems to be assiging the event before the DOM is ready. nice catch +1

Comment: It all depends on where he's including his JavaScript.  If his chunk of code is at the bottom of the `<body>`, it should still work.  Of course, if it's inside his `<head>`, it will fail as the HTML elements do not yet exist.  Either way, I'd still enclose it all within a `$document.ready`

Comment: jquery 1.8 and jquery ui work fine on all browsers. I think you should switch to newer versions.

Comment: **Quote @TigOldBitties:** _"jquery 1.8 and jquery ui work fine"_. There is no such thing as jQuery 1.8, he's not using jQueryUI, and we don't yet know which jQuery color animation plugin is being used.

Comment: @Sparky672 are you kidding me? he's using 1.6.3 with jquery.animate-colors http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ and I meant 1.7 but typed it fast without checking. Obviously I mean he should switch to jQuery UI.

Comment: @TigOldBitties, if he doesn't know how to implement a simple plugin, I don't think he's going to have better luck with jQueryUI (which is overkill in this case). Feel free to post that as your answer though, if you think that's the root cause of his problem.

Comment: Hey everyone, I did add the correct plugin, I just do not know why this is not working :(... if I figure it out I will post it here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"I did add the correct plugin"_.  Again, which plugin??  Nobody can read your mind... we are only assuming you are using this plugin [HERE](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) since you never mentioned it in your posting.  And just surround your jQuery/JS in a `document.ready`, and it works perfect fine... http://jsfiddle.net/nJxVZ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer, already posted by another user, vanished so I'm posting it again along with more of an explanation and a working demo.

Surround your code in a `$(document).ready()` function since apparently none of the relevant DOM elements exist when your code is called.  The `$(document).ready()` fires only after the DOM is fully loaded, thereby allowing proper manipulation or your target elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#sidemenu>a").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#943939",color: "#fff"}, 150 )
        },function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#dcacbb",color: "#8e5769"}, 150 );
    });  

});

</script>
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nJxVZ/1/)

The demo assumes that you are using [this plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the element has background-color pre-defined in CSS..

```
.yourelement { 
    background-color: #FFF; 
}
```

now it should work in Firefox and IE....